# Elastic Search: Update Index or do two Requests

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-schema

Assume following:

I have an entity "Producer" which has an "id", an "alias" and other attributes. The alias is changeable.
Then I have an entity "items" which has some attributes and is produced by a producer (in a relational database it would have a foreign key on "producer.id").

Lets now assume I want to let the user search for items and the alias of the producer is also an option to search for within the items-search.

I can also search for producers.
So I have an index "producer" and an index "items".

What is the best approach to search for the alias within the items-search?

- Do I add "alias" as field within the "items"-index (which means I have to reindex, when an alias is changed- which doesn't happen that often)

or

- Do I search for the producers with the alias first and take the ids to search for the items in a second request? (I would then add the id-field to the items-index)

Answer (score 1):

Parent-child relationships are costly from a performance and implementation point, Distributed systems main capability and power comes when you denormalize the data, and when all the data you need is available together.

The first option is a very common and in-general preferred way for scalable applications, And in your case, it's even less costly as you mentioned it's not updated very frequently. So would advise you to go with the first option, but you can always do the performance and implementation comparison yourself and choose what fits best according to your use-case.